# Importing "wildcard" Maven project dependencies?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have quite a situation here: another team is building a Flex SDK and delivers it as a huge set of separate SWC files. At this point I cannot make them build a single SWC file library.

I'm trying to use these files as Maven dependencies to pass to Flexmojos but they are like 40 files and I don't want to manage each of them as a separate dependency (after all they are parts of the same thing).

Is there a way to:

1. Install all of the SWC files as artifacts in the local repo? (with the same groupId and version and auto-generated artifactId I guess)
2. Import these as dependencies using a "wildcard" or plugin that generates dependencies at runtime or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this won't work that way. Dependency declarations can't be dynamic, this would break the build. What you can do is have your deployers create a rollup pom with packaging pom containing all of the SWC dependencies and deploy that pom into your nexus repository. You'd be able to use that pom dependency. The benefit would be that the pom is maintained in a single central location.

Comment: This is what I suspected as well. 

Okay then, how about I build a plugin that modifies POM at runtime? I saw the interface of MavenProject allows for dynamic dependency registration through setDependencies.

Comment: Dynamic modification of the pom is not a good idea nor will it work and will break the reproducibility of your builds.

Comment: Well, you could fetch all deps from the Model class with [`getDependencies()`](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.maven/maven-model/3.0.3/org/apache/maven/model/ModelBase.java#ModelBase.addDependency%28org.apache.maven.model.Dependency%29) and add your own. I presume that the Maven devs would slap you for this. You should post this rather on the Maven user list.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/index.html) to add artifacts to the Flex SDK project. As a result you can use the SDK project as a dependency and got all files which you can use.

Comment: Karl-Heinz, this would not work either, imho. He wants it completely dynamic out of the code.